# Popup not opening in IE Mode on Edge, opening in IE, (Selenium - Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, automation, microsoft-edge

The webpage im automating is running in Edge IE mode, and i have a link that i click which should open a popup for futher operation. However when i press the link (only when using selenium) it will try to open Internet Explorer and not work, Ive tried forcing the link url to open in IE mode but it wont work, does anyone have any suggestions.

[The popup code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpzuL.png)

I've tried clicking the link to open to tab, which resulted in IE being opened,
Running the open popup through execute_script in selenium, same result.
opening the link in a seperate tab, tab opens correctly, but actions dont on the tab do not affect the original page.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: Do you use IE Driver to automate IE mode in Edge? We can't reproduce the issue with the code picture you provide. Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which we can test and reproduce the issue. You can provide the automation code you use and the website you're trying to automate.